# ASUS ZenBook 3 UX390UA and double monitor

Tags: linux, laptop, display, asus-laptop

I have a Zenbook 3 UX390UA with the universal adapter https://www.asus.com/Laptops-Accessory/Universal-Dock/

I was using an external monitor (https://www.amazon.it/ASUS-VE248H-1920x1080-Back-lit-Monitor/dp/B0043T7FHK/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1501600514&sr=8-2&keywords=monitor+asus+24) via VGA and xrandr detects it as DP-1

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.05 +  59.93    48.04  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The Universal Adapter has HDMI and VGA. I bought another monitor (the same one) and I am trying to use it with the HDMI output. But xrandr doesn't detect it. If I have both connected it detects the new one equal as `DP-1` and the other one is like "overrided" and I can't control it anymore. My idea was to use both of them.

I tried to use them 1 by 1 with both VGA and HDMI and both of them are working fine. They are not working together because both are detected as `DP-1` I think.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have the same laptop but you seem to have missed one important thing on that Universal Dock.

That dock can only use 1 external monitor at a time and it's shown on the official website of the Universal Dock.

> 2.HDMI and VGA port can't be displayed at the same time.

Since it doesn't use Thunderbolt 3 it can only display 1 screen. The new one (UX490UA or Zenbook 3 Deluxe) has Thunderbolt 3 and you should be able to drive at least 2 monitors with the correct adapters.

Comment: Ah bad news. It a laptop limitation and not just an adapter. Sad. :( Thansk

Comment: +sk3 do you think I will be able to have it working this something like this? https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Specific-Chromebook-Thunderbolt-Supported/dp/B01FKMN1BW/ref=sr_1_6?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1507296944&sr=1-6&keywords=plugable+usb-c+to+hdmi+2.0